# Describe the replacement flow of water at the stern of a large ship

Tags: fluid-mechanics, ships, naval-engineering

What is the flow path of water immediately at the stern of a large, deep draft ship (like a container ship 250+m long for example)? Does it fill in the area displaced by the hull from all sides equally? or does more water flow in from the bottom or sides?

This was prompted by a ridiculous video of a guy accidentally pulling the dead man key out of his jetski as he reaches out to try and touch a large commercial freighter resulting in him capsizing next to the ship as it passes.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L3c9IKvfmsQ

At the core of the question is, based on the replacement fluid flow around the stern of the ship, is it ever likely that he would get sucked in behind the ship and risk being killed by the prop?

If someone has a diagram or animation that would be most helpful

Edit - For an example, lets assume the ship's hull looks about like this
[image: Ship Hull Rear]

Comment: Rivers can have reverse flow around objects...

Answer (score 1):

The water stream flow on the back of ship depends on two main factors, ignoring waves and possible wake shock.

- The shape and curve of the wet surface on that section. The more streamlined, the less turbulent flow and ideally less rushing of the water.
- The depth which causes larger hydrostatic pressure. That is the reason they avoid creating a bulkhead at the stern, while providing a linear flow path to feed the propellers.